# Can awk read null delimited text?

Tags: awk

Does `awk` support null delimited inputs like other commands like `sort`, `read`, `grep`, etc.?

I am trying this:

```
printf 'one\0two' | awk -F '\0' '{print $2}'
```

I expected it to output `two` but what I am getting is:

```
n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No standard POSIX tools support that since it's not a POSIX text file (see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) but just like GNU sort, GNU grep, and GNU sed, so does GNU awk support it. YMMV with providing input that's not a valid POSIX text "file" too due to no terminating `\n`.

```
$ printf 'one\0two\n' | gawk -F '\0' '{print $2}'
two
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way to do this, is to use `xargs` :

```sh
$ printf 'one\0two' | xargs -0 -n1 echo
one
two
```